# Float64[9] covariance array in C++

Tags: ros, imu, c++, array

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to fill in an IMU message, and it requires 3 arrays of Float64's.
How can I fill such an array in C++, initializing the first element with value -1 and the other values 0.

The documentation of the message can be found here:
http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Imu.html

I know the C++ double type should be the same as ROS Float64. This doesn't help me much unfortunately, I can't find any way to correctly initialize this array.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272324/float64%5B9%5D-covariance-array-in-c++/) by [Chrizzl](https://answers.ros.org/users/31761/chrizzl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2017-10-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's an example of values of the IMU message covariance array being filled: [UM7 driver main.cpp](https://github.com/ros-drivers/um7/blob/indigo-devel/src/main.cpp#L356). I think this example should clarify it nicely.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2017-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chrizzl](https://answers.ros.org/users/31761/chrizzl/) on 2017-10-05**:
Thank you, the line you linked to was the solution! For completeness that line is below:

```
imu_msg.linear_acceleration_covariance[0] = -1.0;
```